# Using Python script in Web App

Tags: javascript, python, web, matplotlib

I want to use the next Python code in a Web App. I have tried to use Bokeh, Plotly and PyJS but I always receive an error. It doesnt matter if the code is embedded or is converted to JS. I just hope that the code of the solution can be fast, because the idea is to use the script to build a dashboard.

Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 
import pandas as pd

def _scale_data(data, ranges):
    """scales data[1:] to ranges[0],
    """
    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
        assert (y1 <= d <= y2) or (y2 <= d <= y1)
    x1, x2 = ranges[0]
    d = data[0]
    sdata = [d]
    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
        sdata.append((d-y1) / (y2-y1) 
                     * (x2 - x1) + x1)
    return sdata

class ComplexRadar():
    def __init__(self, fig, variables, ranges,
                 n_ordinate_levels=6):
        angles = np.arange(0, 360, 360./len(variables))

        axes = [fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9],polar=True,
                label = "axes{}".format(i)) 
                for i in range(len(variables))]
        l, text = axes[0].set_thetagrids(angles, 
                                         labels=variables)
        [txt.set_rotation(angle-90) for txt, angle 
             in zip(text, angles)]
        for ax in axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
            grid = np.linspace(*ranges[i], 
                               num=n_ordinate_levels)
            gridlabel = ["{}".format(round(x,2)) 
                         for x in grid]
            if ranges[i][0] > ranges[i][1]:
                grid = grid[::-1] # hack to invert grid
                          # gridlabels aren't reversed
            gridlabel[0] = "" # clean up origin
            ax.set_rgrids(grid, labels=gridlabel,
                         angle=angles[i])
            #ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
            ax.set_ylim(*ranges[i])
        # variables for plotting
        self.angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[angles, angles[0]])
        self.ranges = ranges
        self.ax = axes[0]

    def plot(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        l = self.ax.plot(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)
        return l

    def fill(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.fill(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)



index = ["Carl","Michael","Peter","Louis","Sarah", "Laura","Nicholas"]      
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Spe": pd.Series([89, 83, 70, 60, 30, 49, 28]),
    "Str": pd.Series([69, 53, 30, 20, 10, 29, 48]),
    "Det": pd.Series([82, 44, 79, 39, 20, 10, 85]),
    "Extr": pd.Series([59, 74, 29, 36, 18, 29, 18]),
    "Int": pd.Series([63, 11, 20, 36, 97, 58, 91]),
    "Est": pd.Series([12, 69, 89, 59, 19, 58, 98]),
    "Ape": pd.Series([29, 13, 94, 30, 20, 10, 67]),
})

variables = [k[0] for k in df.iteritems()]

ranges = [(1.,100.),(1.,100.),(1.,100.),(1.,100.),(1.,100.),(1.,100.),(1.,100.)] 
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
radar = ComplexRadar(fig1, variables, ranges)
lax = []
for i, name  in enumerate(index):
    data=df.iloc[i].values
    l, = radar.plot(data, label=name)
    lax.append(l)
    radar.fill(data,alpha=0.2)

legendax = fig1.add_axes([0.8,0.8,0.1,.1])
legendax.legend(handles = lax, labels=index, loc=3, bbox_to_anchor=(0,0,1,1), bbox_transform=fig1.transFigure )

legendax.axis('off')
sns.plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a bit of a square hole, round peg issue. You probably want your web application to instead hit an API endpoint to retrieve plot images. Consider using Flask to startup a python server and a short javascript page to request the data you want displayed and return it. If you just want to play with some plot visuals, consider using jupyter notebooks which can render matplotlib directly in a browser cell.

Comment: The browser does not understand python. It will only understand html and JS,Follow what @Pyrce said.

Comment: Hi. I understand that I can only use html and JS. So the best solution to convert the Python code in JS for my Web Application is Flask? Can I mix the HTML code that someone else writes with the code produced by Flask? I want to retrieve data from a server and depending on this data, the plot will be changing in live, so jupyter notebooks are not very useful.